# Dotnet Core - Getting a warning on 'string.Replace(string, string?)' saying use 'string.Replace(string, string?, System.StringComparison)'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn-code-analysis

I m getting the following warning on "Replace"

```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning   CA1307  The behavior of 'string.Replace(string, string?)' could
> vary based on the current user's locale settings. Replace this call in
> 'JobsLedger.API.ControllerServices.Common.OrderAndFIlterHelpers.ODataProcessQuery.ProcessQuery(string)'
> with a call to 'string.Replace(string, string?,
> System.StringComparison)'.    JobsLedger.API  C:\Users\simon\OneDrive\Documents\1.0
> - AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.1\JobsLedger.API\ControllerServices\Common\OrderAndFIlterHelpers\ODataProcessQuery.cs    38  Active
```

I dont know how to reconfigure the following to take into account 'System.StringComparison':

```
                            .Replace("and", "&")
                            .Replace("substringof", string.Empty)
                            .Replace("(", string.Empty)
                            .Replace(")", string.Empty)
                            .Replace("'", string.Empty)
                            .Replace(" ", string.Empty)
                            .Replace("eq", ",")
```

Each line has thrown up a warning..

I am using VS2019 and these warnings are coming from the Roslyn compiler. I would like to get rid of the warnings.. how do I rewrite this to take into account the 'System.StringComparison' part of the Replace?

Comment: You can pass an additional argument `StringComparison` to `Replace` method or configure the warning severity

Comment: I know internationalization is all the rage, but you are replacing ASCII with ASCII, you might just want to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just... tell it what comparison type you want; for example, for an ordinal-ignore-case replace:

```cs
    .Replace("and", "&", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .Replace("substringof", string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .Replace("(", string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .Replace(")", string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .Replace("'", string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .Replace(" ", string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .Replace("eq", ",", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

For descriptions of what each option does, look at [`StringComparison`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netframework-4.8). Generally speaking, you should not use `CurrentCulture` / `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` for hard-coded system-like replacement; culture-based replace is more typical for user-facing replacements (think: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>). As a side-note, there's really no benefit over using `string.Empty` over the clearer (IMO) `""`.